# Alias Column name with spaces throws error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am using this below portion in my stored procedure and it throws the error:-
Error report:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Problem is with column name which contains spaces that line i have highlighted in bold.It is with string concatenation

```
//Evt_label has varchar values with spaces eg. Stack OverFlow

select TYT_LIBELLE into evt_label from trb_type_trv where tyt_id= x.tyt_id;     

 ***sql_Columns := sql_Columns ||',T_"'|| evt_label||'"Total'||vTytCnt;***

//Error Comes when i execute this line

select sql_Columns from table1;
```

Comment: if the single problem is spaces in column names, the solution is simple: put them in double quotes: "Stack Overflow".

Comment: @Florin Ghinta,how to use double quotes in the next statement, sql_Columns := sql_Columns ||',T_"'|| evt_label||'"Total'||vTytCnt;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should surround the entire column name with double quotes but I'm not sure if there is a single column or two

```
sql_Columns ||',"T_'|| evt_label||'Total'||vTytCnt||'"
```

or

```
sql_Columns ||',"T_'|| evt_label||'","Total'||vTytCnt||'"'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` as below:

```
//Evt_label has varchar values with spaces eg. Stack OverFlow

select TYT_LIBELLE into evt_label from trb_type_trv where tyt_id= x.tyt_id;     

 sql_comm := 'select '||sql_Columns ||',T_"'|| evt_label||'"Total'||vTytCnt||' from table1';

//Error Comes when i execute this line

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_comm;
```

Comment: Problem is not in execution,it is in quotes in below lines:-sql_comm := 'select '||sql_Columns ||',T_"'|| evt_label||'"Total'||vTytCnt||' from table1';